# How can I parse complex query operations using Sequelize.js?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database, sequelize.js

I have an `Option` table which has a `question_id` as a foreign key to table `Questions`.
Then in `Questions` table I've 2 foreign keys namely `question_category_id` and `section_id`. For the 1st Option part I am able to apply `LEFT OUTER JOIN` query but also I need to fetch the values of `Question_Category` and `Section` table as well.
Let me first clear out how I want my output to be:

**Output JSON**

```
"questions": [
  {
    "id": 9,
    "isActive": true,
    "question_text": "What is abc ?",
    "createdBy": "avis",
    "questionCategory": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "aptitude"
    },
    "section": {
      "id": 1,
      "marks": 5
    },
    "options": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        "answer": true,
        "option_text": "A",
        "question_id": 9
      },
      {
        "id": 2,
        "answer": false,
        "option_text": "B",
        "question_id": 9
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Now I am specifying my database models:

**question_category.js**

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    const QuestionCategory = sequelize.define('question_category', {
        id:{ type: Sequelize.BIGINT, autoIncrement: true, allowNull: false, primaryKey: true }, 
        isActive: { type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN, allowNull: false },
        question_category_name: { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false },
        createdBy: { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false },
        createdAt: { type: Sequelize.DATE, allowNull: false, defaultValue: Sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP') }
    }, { timestamps: false });

    return QuestionCategory;
};
```

**section.js**

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    const Section = sequelize.define('section', {
        id: { type: Sequelize.BIGINT, autoIncrement: true, allowNull: false, primaryKey: true },
        isActive: { type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN, allowNull: false },
        marks_per_question: { type: Sequelize.INTEGER, allowNull: false },
        createdBy: { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false },
        createdAt: { type: Sequelize.DATE, allowNull: false, defaultValue: Sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP') }
    }, { timestamps: false });

    return Section;
};
```

**question.js**

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    const Questions = sequelize.define('questions', {
        id:{ type: Sequelize.BIGINT, autoIncrement: true, allowNull: false, primaryKey: true }, 
        isActive: { type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN, allowNull: false },
        question_text: { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false },
        createdBy: { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false },
        createdAt: { type: Sequelize.DATE, allowNull: false, defaultValue: Sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP') }
    }, { timestamps: false });

    return Questions;
};
```

**option.js**

```
module.exports = (sequelize, Sequelize) => {
    const Options = sequelize.define('options', {
        id:{ type: Sequelize.BIGINT, autoIncrement: true, allowNull: false, primaryKey: true }, 
        answer: { type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN, allowNull: true },
        option_text: { type: Sequelize.STRING, allowNull: false },
        createdAt: { type: Sequelize.DATE, allowNull: false, defaultValue: Sequelize.literal('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP') }
    }, { timestamps: false });

    return Options;
};
```

In the **database.js** i.e. the main js file for exporting the models I have associated the models like this:

```
const dbConfig = require('../config/db.config');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');

const sequelize = new Sequelize(
    dbConfig.DB, dbConfig.USER, dbConfig.PASSWORD,
    {
        host: dbConfig.HOST,
        port: dbConfig.PORT,
        dialect: 'mysql',
        operatorsAliases: 0
    }
);

sequelize.authenticate().then(() => {
console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
}).catch(err => {
    console.error('Unable to connect to the database:', err);
});

const db = {};

db.Sequelize = Sequelize;
db.sequelize = sequelize;

db.QuestionCategory = require('./question_model/question_category')(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.Section = require('./question_model/section')(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.Question = require('./question_model/question')(sequelize, Sequelize);
db.Option = require('./question_model/option')(sequelize, Sequelize);

// Relating Question Category with Questions
db.QuestionCategory.hasMany(db.Question, {
    foreignKey: 'question_category_id',
    sourceKey: 'id'
});
db.Question.belongsTo(db.QuestionCategory, {
    foreignKey: 'question_category_id',
    targetKey: 'id'
});

// Relating Sections with Questions
db.Section.hasMany(db.Question, {
    foreignKey: 'section_id',
    sourceKey: 'id'
});
db.Question.belongsTo(db.Section, {
    foreignKey: 'section_id',
    targetKey: 'id'
});

// Relating Questions with Options
db.Question.hasMany(db.Option, {
    foreignKey: 'question_id',
    sourceKey: 'id'
});
db.Option.belongsTo(db.Question, {
    foreignKey: 'question_id',
    targetKey: 'id'
});
```

So this is my structure.
Now to achieve the above output format I've written the below logic but it's not outputting the correct JSON:

```
const db = require('../models/database');
const errors = require('../config/errors').errors;

exports.viewQuestion = (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    db.Question.findAll({ 
      attributes: { exclude: ['createdAt','section_id','question_category_id'] },
      include: [{
        model: db.Option,
        attributes: { exclude: ['createdAt'] }
      }]
    }).then(data => {
        if(data.length == 0) {
          return res.status(200).send({
            status: 200,
            questions: 'No Data'
          });
        }
        db.QuestionCategory.findAll({
          attributes: { exclude: ['createdBy','createdAt','isActive'] },
          include: db.Question,
          attributes: { exclude: ['id','isActive','question_text','createdBy','createdAt','section_id'] }
        }).then(question_category => {
          Object.assign(data[0], { 'questionCategories': question_category });
          res.status(200).send({
            status: 200,
            questions: data
          });
        });
      }).catch(err => {
        return res.status(204).send(errors.MANDATORY_FIELDS);
      });
  } catch(err) {
    return res.status(204).send(errors.MANDATORY_FIELDS);
  }
};
```

I didn't wrote the logic for `Section` part yet as I was going Step by Step. The output that I am getting by writing this logic is:

```
{
    "status": 200,
    "questions": [
        {
            "id": 9,
            "isActive": true,
            "question_text": "What is abc ?",
            "createdBy": "avis",
            "options": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "answer": true,
                    "option_text": "A",
                    "question_id": 9
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "answer": false,
                    "option_text": "B",
                    "question_id": 9
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The `questionCategories` didn't got reflected in the output.

Please help me out as I've more scenarios like this and all I can solve depending on this.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Sequelize to get objects from a DB via models then you should turn them into plain objects before adding some properties. For instance, if you get a collection of objects you should call `get({ plain: true })` for each of them.

```
const plainObj = data[0].get({ plain: true })
Object.assign(plainObj, { 'questionCategories': question_category });
          res.status(200).send({
            status: 200,
            questions: plainObj
          });
```

Comment: thanks for this info. But can you please help me how I can get the desired output I want ? I don't think my logic will help and also it's a bit complex

Comment: Why don't you add `QuestionCategory` in `include` option of the `db.Question.findAll`?

Comment: will that work ? I mean will it find the rows that are getting matched ??

Comment: Just try out and you'll find out )